# Oracle bulk collect into three column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

How in below function add more than one eg. `l_col2` and `l_col3`

```
l_col2 =  Select sal as val2 from emp where empno = P_ID

l_col3 =  Select deptno as val3 from emp where empno = P_ID
```

---

```
create or replace function F_MY_FUNC
    ( 
         P_ID IN number
       )
          return  sys.odcinumberlist
        as
          l_coll  sys.odcinumberlist;
        begin
          select * bulk collect into l_coll
          from (  
                 Select ename as val from emp where empno = P_ID
                 union all
                 Select ename as val from myemp where empno = P_ID
              );
    
         return l_coll;
       end;
```

Comment: You're trying to return string into array of numbers.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  I need function with one parameter, ibb.co/ygjhGZ6  in function need put below sql code  from Littlefoot

Answer (score 1):

You can, but not into `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` - create your own type.

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row as object
  2    (empno number, ename varchar2(10), job varchar2(10));
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab as
  2    table of t_row;
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_tab t_tab;
  3  begin
  4    select t_row(empno, ename, job)      --> 3 columns 
  5      bulk collect into l_tab            --> into one collection
  6      from emp
  7      where deptno = 20;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: is it possible put  (SQL> declare   2    l_tab t_tab....)  in function with one parameter and parameter 20 replace with my parameter?  And then call Select * from my_func(parameter) and get resaults select with 3 column?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: What is `my_function` and what do you want to do with the `20`? By the way, you don't need to create an object type, a plain PL/SQL collection of records will do fine.

Comment: @Littlefoot  Something like this ibb.co/ygjhGZ6

Comment: Some times we may not need to declare types at schema level and make use of existing record and table types from DBMS_SQL pkg. [Oracle 12.2 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-F85DE431-2B29-4C3A-B934-A7037EFC0BCA)